# Microservice instances (Dockerized) with slightly different parameters in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I’m somewhat new to Kubernetes and not sure the standard way to do this. I’d like to have many instances of a single microservice, but with each of the containers parameterized slightly differently. (Perhaps an environment variable passed to the container that’s different for each instance, as specified in the container spec of the .yaml file?)

It seems like a single deployment with multiple replicas wouldn’t work. Yet, having n different deployments with very slightly different .yaml files seems a bit redundant. Is there some sort of templating solution perhaps?

Or should each microservice be identical and seek out its parameters from a central service?

I realize this could be interpreted as an “opinion question” but I am looking for typical solutions.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "many" here?
Are we talking about 5 instances of your microservice which you could still handle manually or thousands of services which need to be configured automatically (like just with an incremented ID in the config or something like this)?

Comment: For example, 100 microservices share the work of processing data from 1000 cameras, each of which has a different IP address. Should there be a central service that doles out these IP addresses? or a central database? Any other way to do it?

Comment: Based on that example, I'd say setting up a fixed amout of pods for each camera is probably not the way to go. That kind of sounds like you're trying to replace servers with pods with the same approach. Depending on what you would do with those cameras, you could for example create a database and use your pods as workers. If it's a recurring job, also Kubernetes cronjobs could help. Or a message queue system to distribute work.
Maybe you should open a question with a more precise example, then you could get better architectural guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely several ways of doing it. One popular option is to use [Helm](https://helm.sh/). Helm lets you define kubernetes manifests using Go templates, and package them on a single unit called a Helm Chart. Later on you can install this Chart (install is what Helm calls to save these manifests in the Kubernetes API). When installing the Helm Chart, you can pass arguments that will be used when rendering the templates. That way you can re-use pretty much everything, and just replace the significant bits of your manifests: Deployments, Services, etc.

There are [plenty of Helm charts available as open sources projects](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable), that you can use as an example on how to create your own Chart.

And many [useful guides on how to create your first Helm Chart](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/create-your-first-helm-chart/).

Here you can find the [official docs on developing your own Charts](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/).

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can use [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) with [InitContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) plus [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).

Statefulset will guarantee you proper naming and order.
ConfigMap will let you store fine-grained information like individual properties or coarse-grained information like entire config files.

Configuration data can be consumed in pods in a variety of ways. ConfigMaps can be used to:

1) Populate the values of environment variables

2) Set command-line arguments in a container

3) Populate config files in a volume

For the begging you can review [Kubernetes – StatefulSets](https://theithollow.com/2019/04/01/kubernetes-statefulsets/) article where you can find a good explanation on how this pieces work together and inspect prepared example on how to deploy containers from the same image but with different properties.

Comment: Appreciate it, but is the last link correct? It brought me to a page on "Init Containers"

Comment: Using a ConfigMap is a good idea. Hmm, trying to wrap my head around the example. I can think of doing the following: StatefulSet with a 100 replica Pod defined, that has an InitContainer that uses pod ordinal index to set an environment variable. If you have something else in mind let me know.